# Find trimmed average of an array excluding the min and max value

Tags: java, arrays

was looking to find the trimmed average of an array but am stumped on how to implement it using a method. Please shoot any ideas on how to implement and get the actual trimmed average using a method.
This is all I have at the moment. TIA!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Program 1: Average, Min, Max, Trimmed Average of Array
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[] {88,48,96,85,97,68,97};

    // Calling getMax() method for getting max value
    int max = getMax(array);
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);

    // Calling getMin() method for getting min value
    int min = getMin(array);
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);

    // calling getAvg() method for getting avg value
    double avg = getAvg(array);
    System.out.println("Average: " + avg);

    // calling getMean() method for getting trimmed mean value
    double mean = getTrim(array);
    System.out.println("Trimmed mean: " + mean);
}

// Method for getting the maximum value
public static int getMax(int[] inputArray) {
    int maxValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// Method for getting the minimum value
public static int getMin(int[] inputArray) {
    int minValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

//Method for getting the avg value
public static double getAvg(int[] inputArray) {
    double total = 0;
    double avg;
    for(int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
        total = total + inputArray[i];
    }
    return avg = total / inputArray.length;
}

//Method for getting the trimmed mean value
public static double getTrim(int[] inputArray) {

}
```

}

Comment: Calculate the sum of all values by iterating the array, keeping track of the max and the min as you go. Then take off the max and min at the end.

Comment: @AndyTurner could you give me an example of how to iterate it so the max and min could be removed? pretty new to java and online tutorials aren't helping much. never encountered trimmed averages before(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating average without highest and lowest values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029024/calculating-average-without-highest-and-lowest-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static double avgExcludingMinMax(int[] inputArray) {
    int max = inputArray[0];
    int min = inputArray[0];
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        sum = sum + inputArray[i];
        if (inputArray[i] > max) {
            max = inputArray[i];
        }
        if (inputArray[i] < min) {
            min = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return ((double) (sum - max - min)) / (inputArray.length - 2);
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception if inputArray.length == 0;

If you want to read more about the statistical background of such an operation, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing!

Comment: this answer will not return right value, because (sum - max - min) / inputArray.length; //will generate int value, you have to cast one of operand of / to double

Comment: This doesn't calculate the right value because you need to subtract 2 the denominator.

Comment: thanks so much guys. checked out the wiki page as well that @tjfuller recommended and understood how it works)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fully finished program :D

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Program 1: Average, Min, Max, Trimmed Average of Array
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[] { 88, 48, 96, 85, 97, 68, 97 };

    int max = getMax(array);
    System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);

    int min = getMin(array);
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);

    double avg = getAvg(array);
    System.out.println("Average: " + avg);

    double mean = getTrim(array);
    System.out.println("Trimmed mean: " + mean);
}

public static int getMax(int[] inputArray) {
    int maxValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

public static int getMin(int[] inputArray) {
    int minValue = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}

public static double getAvg(int[] inputArray) {
    double total = 0;
    double avg;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        total = total + inputArray[i];
    }
    return avg = total / inputArray.length;
}

public static double getTrim(int[] inputArray) {
    int max = getMax(inputArray);
    int min = getMin(inputArray);
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + inputArray[i];
        if (inputArray[i] > max) {
            max = inputArray[i];
        }
        if (inputArray[i] < min) {
            min = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return ((double) (sum - max - min)) / (inputArray.length - 2);
}
```

}