# Average Salary Excluding the Minimum and Maximum Salary

Tags: javascript, arrays

the leet code question states,

> You are given an array of unique integers salary where salary[i] is the salary of the ith employee.
> Return the average salary of employees excluding the minimum and maximum salary. Answers within 10-5 of the actual answer will be accepted.

i expect to start off the first indices with `let sal = salary[0]`, i wanted to compare the other salaries to `salary[0]` and if it was less, i wanted to push the lower salaries into a new array. however im not sure how to seperate the lowest salary or finish the problem

```
/**
* @param {number[]} salary
* @return {number}
*/
var average = function(salary) {
    let sal = salary[0]
    for(let i = 1; i < salary.length; i++){
        if (sal > salary[i]) {
            salary.map()
        }
    }
 

};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating average without highest and lowest values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029024/calculating-average-without-highest-and-lowest-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

For that I would sort the array, and then remove the first and last elements, since the first one will be the lowest salary, and the last one will be the highest salary. Then, with the trimmed array, I'd do the average:

```js
var average = (salary) => {
    const sortedArray = salary.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    const trimmedArray = sortedArray.slice(1, -1);

    const sum = trimmedArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)

    return sum / trimmedArray.length;
}
```

**EDIT**

Following @ManuelMB's comment, I have adjusted the `sort` method passing a callback to force the sorting by the numeric value, not the string value of the items on the array.

Comment: It's not right, consider const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
const trimmedArray = salary.sort().slice(1, -1);

trimmedArray
(8) [10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: @ManuelMB your're right, the sorting requires a callback to correctly specify that I want a sorted array by the items numeric values, not string values. I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following code computes the average in one pass, by looking at each salary exactly once and evaluating its effects on the count, the total, the minimum and the maximum.

While adding up salaries, it is not yet known which ones will be the minimum and maximum, therefore *all* salaries are added up at first, and the minimum and maximum are subtracted again at the end.

```js
const salaries = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let count = 0;
let total = 0;
let min = Infinity;
let max = -Infinity;
for (const salary of salaries) {
  count++;
  total += salary;
  if (salary < min) min = salary;
  if (salary > max) max = salary;
}
if (count > 2)
  console.log((total - min - max) / (count - 2));
```

The computation of `count`, `min` and `max` could be simplified with `salaries.length`, `Math.min` and `Math.max`, respectively.

Comment: This is the first and only correct answer that isn't unnecessarily slow (+1). A few suggestions: use `let` or `const` instead of `var`; use `Math.min` and `Math.max` instead of manual comparisions; `count` can be replaced with `salaries.length`.

Comment: I want to avoid the use of `salaries.length`, because the same idea can be applied if `salaries` is an asynchronous iterator when `salaries.length` is not available. Similarly if different concepts of minimum and maximum were used (think of 2- or 3-dimensional vectors with the shortest and longest excluded).

Answer (score 1):

```
    const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
var average = function(salary) { 
    const max = Math.max(...salary)
    const min = Math.min(...salary)
        
    const maxIndex = salary.indexOf(max)
    const minIndex = salary.indexOf(min)
        
    salary.splice(maxIndex, 1); // Remove one item at index maxIndex
    salary.splice(minIndex, 1); // Remove one item at index minIndex
        
    const sum = salary.reduce((pre,curr)=>pre+curr,0) 
    const elements = salary.length
    return sum/elements
};
console.log(average(array)) // 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const average = (salaries) => {
    if(salaries.length <= 2) return 0;
    // This could be done in one pass, but we do it like this for the sake of convenience
    // The max/min could technically be found in one iteration but the JS Math library does not support it,
    // it would be rather trivial to implement one if this became a performance issue, but it likely wont
    const max = Math.max(...salaries);
    const min = Math.min(...salaries);


    // take advantage of the fact that all salaries are unique, so we can do direct comparisons.
    const net = salaries.reduce((total, s) => s != min && s != max ? total + s : total , 0);
    return net / (salaries.length - 2);
}
```

Comment: if(salaries.length === 1)  should return the value of this salary

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At first we sort the `salary` array and then remove the lowest salary and highest salary via `slice(1,-1)`.

For the `sort` function we need a compare function because the default `sort` function sorts numbers like strings: `1, 10, 2, 3, ...`

And then with the trimmed salary we can do the average.

I think also that the solution should calculate cases if `salary.length` is less than `3`.

```js
var salary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function average(salary)
{
  var sorted = salary.sort(compareNumbers),
      trimmedSalary = sorted.slice(1,-1),
      sum = 0,
      len = trimmedSalary.length,
      i = len;
  
  if(salary.length == 2)
    return(salary[0] + salary[1]) / 2;
  
  if(!len) //if salary.length == 1
    return sorted[0];
  
  while(i--)
    sum += trimmedSalary[i];

  return sum / len
}

function compareNumbers(a, b)
{
  return a - b
}

console.log(average(salary)); //5.5
console.log(average([4,10])); //7
console.log(average([10])); //10
```

## ES6 solution

```js
var salary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var averageES6 = (salary) => {
  
  if(salary.length == 2)
    return(salary[0] + salary[1]) / 2;
  
  if(salary.length == 1)
    return salary[0];
  
  var trimmedSalary = salary.sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(1, -1);

  var sum = trimmedSalary.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);

  return sum / trimmedSalary.length
}

console.log(averageES6(salary)); //5.5
console.log(averageES6([4,10])); //7
console.log(averageES6([10])); //10
```

Answer (score -1):

you can first sort the array then do what ever you want

```
var average = function (salary) {
    let sortedArr = salary.sort()
    let avg = 0;
    //start from 1 to ignore the first element(smallest salary) and end in salary.length-1 to ignore the last element(biggest salary)
    for (let i = 1; i < salary.length - 1; i++) {
        avg += sortedArr[i]
    }
    return avg / (salary.length - 2);

    // you can get the smallest salary by sortedArr[0]
    // you can get the biggest salary by sortedArr[sortedArr.length - 1]
};
```

Comment: This suffers from the same sorting issue: the numbers are converted to strings and sorted alphabetically. You need to pass a number comparison function (`(a, b) => a - b`) to `sort`.